# Okta sign-in widget: Add custom query params to /token API call during login

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, okta

I have used OKTA sign-in widget with angular, using okta.token.getWithoutPrompt to get id and access tokens that in turn calls the okta inline hook.

But i want to pass custom query params to the /token API like /token?app_id=CLIENT_PORTAL so that my inline hook figures out the app that is calling it.

Is there any way to either override the /token url or just append paramaters to it with the okta sign-in angular widget

Comment: is this info not available in the hook context? I believe is should be visible to the hook, which client_id is trying to obtain a token

Comment: @PhilippGrigoryev if i pass a query param to /token api like this /token?app_id=PORTAL. I can get this as inline hook's payload. But that the question, how do i pass a query parameter to the token api using the okta sign in widget for angular

Comment: @PhilippGrigoryev yes youre right, i can get the client_id but then i will have to hardcode the mapping of client_id to a name such as CLIENT_PORTAL. I just want to try and avoid this id mapping. anyway this will be my last resort if i cant do it with the sign in widget

Comment: You can use Okta Apps API to retrieve a name of your app by its client_id from within your hook

Comment: @PhilippGrigoryev sure that can work, but inline hook itself has a hard limit of <3s timeout. So, wont want to add more over the internet API calls to it as the hook is in lambda and already cold starts take it close to the edge

Comment: Yeah, tough situation. I think you can add a claim into your token with an application name, which you can use inside your hook then.